# How could I add Link with jQuery.eraser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am trying the jQuery.eraser plugin .

After user scratched the first picture , they will see one girl .

I want that picture link to URL (example : www.google.com).

But it doesn't work . How could I add  into thr HTML . And get it work .

[here is my JDfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pattydraw/8j4Aq/1/)

Thank sooooo much !

```
<span class="container">
        <a href="htttp://www.google.com"><img id="robot" src="http://www.teenvogue.com/blog/teen-vogue-daily/mkerr.jpg" /></a>
        <img id="redux" src="http://www.fashionmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Fashion-By-Age.jpg" />
    </span>
```

Patty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the eraser is rendering in Canvas, and the image is not clickable in the top, you won't be able to link the image. Even if you link it, it will not be above for the user to click on it.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can do ?

Comment: I guess no! You can do using JS I guess.. After the erase operation is completed, you can make the canvas clickable and send the browser to the new link.